# AWS (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret

Tags: aws-secrets-manager

Having ResourceNotFoundException when using secrets ARN

Tried getting secret only using secret name - doesn't work.
Tried getting secret using ARN - doesn't work.
I've checked my assumed role's policy and SM is set as far as I understand like this in the JSON format "secretsmanager:*"

The command I'm using in a CloudBees job is this:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <ARN>
```

Not sure what is the issue at the moment. All help appreciated!

Dave

Answer (score 12):

There is not enough information here to tell for sure what the problem is. However, the command line you have does not specify a region and you may be defaulting to the wrong region. Pass --region REGION to the CLI (where REGION is the real region name; e.g. us-east-1) and make sure REGION is the same as the region in the ARN.

Comment: --region flag tripped me up. Unhelpful error message as per.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this one as well, my issue was the id was wrong.

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <ARN>
```

The ARN actually needed to be the secret name.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a secret resource without any **secret value** configured

You can verify that the **secret resource** exists using -

```
aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id <ARN or NAME>
```

Quoted from AWS CLI aws secretsmanager command documentation:

--secret-id (string)

> The ARN or name of the secret to add a new version to.
>
> For an ARN, we recommend that you specify a complete ARN rather than a
> partial ARN.

In case you receive the **secret resource** details you may need to set a secret value using the command:

```
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id <ARN or NAME> --secret-string '[{"user":"username"},{"pass":"password"}]'
```

And after the secret resource value is set you should be able to use **get-secret-value** command

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when mocking **Secretes Manager** with https://github.com/getmoto/moto (MOTO) library.

Removing **AWS_DEFAULT_REGION** env variable *solved my problem.*